# How to use constraints in landscape mode

Tags: swift, constraints

In portrait mode, my screen is completely normal when I adjust the constrains. But when I flip, my top view and bottom view become almost equal. How do I adjust them to look like in portrait mode.

[image]

[image]

I tried looking on YouTube, but there is no similar content to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is related to constant value for top constraint.
indeed, I see contraint is ALWAYS 198, and 198 both landscape and portrait.

try to set constraint with:

1. constant 0
2. multiplier as you want.

[image][image]

[image]